# Inserting new entity into or deleting entity from database with position attribute

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.3

So let's say, I got 20 entities in my database already, each of them having a position attribute to display what entity comes first on my website.

If I add a entity, I would like to actually make the position the first, so the position would be 0 at smallest as this would be my newest entity.

OR

If I remove an entity, I would like the other entities to adjust to this and fill the gap so to say.

Though there are already 20 entities in the database with positions ranging from 0-19.

All the positions can be rearranged hence the position attribute.

How would I go about this?

I know a solution by getting all the entities and iterating over them to add 1 to their position on new entity or by subtracting 1 to the position higher than the deleted one but that seems abit over the top.

## Edit:

Thanks to the SQL answer, I made the answer which was:

```
    public function setPositions($position = 0){
        $query = $this->createQueryBuilder()
            ->update('Entity', 'e')
            ->set('e.position', 'e.position + 1')
            ->where('e.position >= :position')
            ->setParameter('position', $position)
            ->getQuery();

        $query->execute();
    }
```

If you put this in the Repository of your entity you can call it in your controller like:

```
    $this->getRepository('Entity')->setPositions();
```

or

```
    $this->getRepository('Entity')->setPositions( $entityToBeDeleted->getPosition() );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it in one mysql query

```
UPDATE TABLE myTable
SET position = position + 1
WHERE position >= MyPosition
```

MyPosition shoul be passed as parameter from php code

Comment: I will accept your answer even though this is the correct way for SQL, not Symfony, but it made me make the Doctrine Query Language for this code which works.